# Retrieving Data From formData in Rails jquery-file-upload

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, form-data

I am trying to add additional form data by using https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-form-data this tutorial for jQuery-File-Upload plugin in my Rails app.

I'm following the instructions for Setting formData on upload start for each individual file upload.

My problem is, after saving the files with their titles as explained in tutorial, I cannot show them in the final table, because I don't know how to reach the formData's values.

How should I reach the data inside  `data.formData = inputs.serializeArray();` and post them next to each item ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this data would be included as part of `params` inside your controller.

Comment: but all of my computation are made in my models once I open the index.html.erb

Comment: The problem is retrieving the additional data that I manually add. For example with PHP, it can be retrieved by writing $titles = $_POST['title']. However I'm stuck in rails :/

Comment: @CanCeylan If you have a method defined in your model, you can pass in whatever data you want from the controller when you call that method. Pass in the data from `params`.